# Android SDK 64 bit, java 32 bit getting error "Java started but returned exit code 13". How to run 64 bit java?

Tags: android, sdk, jvm, 32bit-64bit, android-sdk-tools

I'm moving my first steps in android developement, so I got to the android developement site and followed their guide to get started.

They suggest you to install Android ADT which basically is an all-in-one solution with eclipse, sdk and everything needed.

So I did, I have windows 7 home premium 64 bit I extracted the content and tried to run eclipse but I get the aforementioned error "Java started but returned exit code 13"

Long story short, typing  in cmd "java -version" gives me this as result:

C:\Users\User123>java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

From what I've read "Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing)" means youre running 32bit java.

Now, how I force eclipse to use 64 bit java? Is already installed or is a complete different setup?

But most important, why the hell java thought it was a good idea to install a 32 bit version on a 64 bit computer? It took the downloading browser settings?? or what?

This is the log

```
>!SESSION 2014-11-09 19:48:37.464 -----------------------------------------------
>eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
>java.version=1.8.0_25
>java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
>BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
>Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
>Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product >com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
>
>!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-11-09 19:48:42.519
>!MESSAGE Application error
>!STACK 1
>java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
>   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:260)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:653)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:154)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:96)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at >org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:>110)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall both java JDK , android SDK  and installed it again

[java JDK 64](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

[Android SDK 32/64](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download)

dont forget to add java jdk to your PATH in Environment Variables

Comment: for the moment the only thing I had to do is download and install [link]filehippo.com/it/download_jre_64[/link] and eclipse started normally.

Funnily enough, ther was no easy and intuitive ways  to download it from Java official site.

I won't comment about Oracle otherwise I would get banned in -0.1 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I had to download a 64 bit version of java from filehippo.com/it/download_jre_64 ad there was no immediate and easy way to do it from hava official website unless you have a 64 bit browser, so I had to find some workaround (to download a product from its official website, wow!). After installing it, running "java -version" in cmd, was showing "Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode, sharing)" which was just what I needed. Now all is fine.

Funnily, I can't still write a single line of code if I don't install another load of plugins, tools and  other stuff from the SDK manager, while on the android website the android ADT package was advertised as an all-in-one solution.

Eheh... damn you programming... Should have studied engineering or something